# macro definitions in gSoap

Tags: c++, web-services, wsdl, gsoap

Does anyone know if and/or how you can define macro definitions in a gSoap header file?

In C++ I can do:

```
 #define maxRecords 100
```

Can I do anything similar in gSoap?

Comment: gsoap produces normal headers and sources you can edit, so you can...

Comment: Every time you recompile your headers you would loss you edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not supposed to ever modify header files from packages (unless you've copied them locally and know what you're doing). You can add that define to your main `.cpp` file before you include anything else and it'll have the same effect. Better yet, create your own `global.h`, put your `#define` in there, and include it anywhere you include gSoap.

You can even make it a gSoap wrapper by putting the gSoap `#include` within your `global.h` and just `#include global.h` instead of `#include <whatevergsoapiscalled.h>`